Merge Conflict Causes SyntaxError in PyTorch Lightning Training Script
I’m encountering an issue while training a machine learning program using PyTorch Lightning in VSCode. I made some changes in another branch of the project, and when I merged the branches, my current program was affected by these changes.
/Users/kaiqu/anaconda3/envs/image/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/callbacks/model_checkpoint.py:653: Checkpoint directory /Users/kaiqu/Developer/kaggle-birdclef-2024/models/efficientnet_b3_2024_06_02-04_55_39 exists and is not empty.
Epoch 14: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████| 612/612 [04:22<00:00,  2.33it/s, v_num=279, train_loss=1.800, val_score=0.978, val_loss=4.590]`Trainer.fit` stopped: `max_epochs=15` reached.                                                                                                      
Epoch 14: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████| 612/612 [04:22<00:00,  2.33it/s, v_num=279, train_loss=1.800, val_score=0.978, val_loss=4.590]
Start validating...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/kaiqu/anaconda3/envs/image/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 122, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/kaiqu/anaconda3/envs/image/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 131, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "/Users/kaiqu/anaconda3/envs/image/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 246, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "/Users/kaiqu/anaconda3/envs/image/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 297, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 285, in run_path
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 259, in _get_code_from_file
  File "/Users/kaiqu/Developer/kaggle-birdclef-2024/src/train.py", line 19
    <<<<<<< HEAD
    ^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Why the change made after a program runs would affect the running program? A bit confused. Thanks a lot for the time and help!


I'm not familiar with PyTorch Lightning, but FWIW, it seems obvious from the traceback: multiprocessing uses runpy which calls _get_code_from_file, which tries to compile the file.

I'm not sure I understand the question. Train.py is your own file. There's no conflict in / caused by pytorch. We don't know what commands were ran between each highlighted line of output, such as git merge

There is no command run in between. I just edited train.py after it has run, and then the running program gets affected by my edit...
